# Right Click and Open In A New tab in protractor

Tags: protractor

I need to right click on a link and open it in a new tab in protractor.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
let gmailElement = element(by.linkText("Gmail"));
browser.actions().mouseMove(gmailElement).perform();

browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
browser.actions().mouseMove(gmailElement)
       .keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).click().perform();

browser.actions().mouseMove(gmailElement)
       .keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).click()
       .keyUp(protractor.Key.CONTROL).perform();
```